# How to config a dimension of Saiku in mysql

Tags: mysql, saiku

Recently I am trying to use Saiku http://meteorite.bi/saiku.
I have a mysql table, which stores statistics for each day. Its schema is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `f_android_active_user_data` (
  `event_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_user_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I want to config event_date as a dimension, however, I don't see an example of how to use a table's own column as a dimension. It seems there's not much material about Saiku. Could anybody help on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Flat-table design is not recommended for data-mart but it's not impossible.

As someone who is keeping very strict to the book (which showed as best in practice), I have to advice you to create time dimension in separate table. Even the date as primary key in time_dimension_table, and as join is not too bad solution.

**Option 1 - Easiest and the worst one**

Define Dimension in your schema mondarian.xml:

```
  <Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" highCardinality="false" name="DateDimension">
    <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="event_date">
      <Table name="f_android_active_user_data" schema="public">
      </Table>
      <Level name="DateLevel" visible="true" column="event_date" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
```

Then, inside your cube define dimension usage:

```
<DimensionUsage source="DateDimension" name="DateDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="event_date" highCardinality="false">
</DimensionUsage>
```

**Option 2 - Create DateDimension table and still use natural key for joins**

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables) to create DateDimension. Make it sure to cover the first showed date in your fact table (f_android_active_user_data).
In this case, defining dimension is going to be changed a bit:

*Note that you could filter and group by months, quarters, years ect*

```
<Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" highCardinality="false" name="DateDimension">
    <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="dt">
      <Table name="calendar_table" schema="public">
      </Table>
      <Level name="YearLevel" visible="true" column="y" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeYears" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="MonthLevel" visible="true" column="m" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
      <Level name="DateLevel" visible="true" column="dt" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeDays" hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
```

**Option 3 - Kimball would be proud**

Use the tutorial linked in option 2, but add PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY as AUTO INCREMENT.
Run this query onse:

```
ALTER table f_android_active_user_data ADD column DATE_FK INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
UPDATE f_android_active_user_data
SET DATE_FK = calendar_table.PK
FROM calendar_table
WHERE f_android_active_user_data.event_date = calendar_table.dt
```

Now, there is only left to set up a trigger:
It's best to be AFTER INSERT TRIGER:

```
 UPDATE f_android_active_user_data
    SET DATE_FK = calendar_table.PK
    FROM calendar_table
    WHERE f_android_active_user_data.event_date = calendar_table.dt AND DATE_FK = NULL
```